# Add Odata query param to @html.Routelink

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, odata

I have a **routelink** :

```
@Html.RouteLink("Campaigns", "DefaultApi", new { controller = "Campaign", httproute = true })
```

that results in `"http://localhost:54614/api/v0.1/ReportData/Account"`

what I want to do is write a **Routelink** - that would result in

```
"http://localhost:54614/api/v0.1/ReportData/Account/?$top=20"
```

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You you can't use `$top` as a property name in an anonymous type so you should use a different `Routelink` overload which uses `RouteValueDictionary`.

But the problem is that `RouteLink` uses `Uri.EscapeUriString` to escape the route values so using the following code:

```
@Html.RouteLink("Campaigns", "DefaultApi", new RouteValueDictionary
                                              {
                                                  { "controller", "Campaign"} ,
                                                  { "httproute", true },
                                                  { "$top", 20 }
                                              })
```

Will produce this url: `/api/Campaign?%24top=20` (see the `$` was encoded to `%24`)

However using a very very dirty hack namely `Uri.UnescapeDataString`:

```
@Html.Raw(Uri.UnescapeDataString(
    @Html.RouteLink("Campaigns", "DefaultApi", new RouteValueDictionary
                                        {
                                            { "controller", "Campaign"} ,
                                            { "httproute", true },
                                            { "$top", 20 }
                                        }).ToHtmlString()))
```

You can get: `/api/Campaign?$top=20`